# Plan not shown as hyperlink when selected from sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want do see the cached plans of queries that were executed on my SQLServer.

When I query the plan from `sys.dm_exec_query_plan` the SQLServer Management Studio nicely displays the plan as a hyperlink. I click this link, a new tab opens and displays the plan.

```sql
SELECT p.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans ps
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ps.plan_handle) p
```

I read `sys.dm_exec_query_plan` may return `NULL` under certain cirumstances and therefore want to query my plan data from `sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan`

```
SELECT p.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans ps
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(ps.plan_handle, 0, -1) p
```

Now, in the results pane, the query plan is not displayed as a hyperlink. How can I view this plan in a graphic display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `query_plan` from `dm_exec_query_plan` shows the hyperlink is that it has an `XML` data type, wheres this column is an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` datatype in `dm_exec_text_query_plan`.  You can convert this column from `dm_exec_text_query_plan` to XML to be displayed in the same format as `dm_exec_query_plan`, however it will fail at times with an `XML datatype instance has too many levels of nested nodes. Maximum allowed depth is 128 levels.` error for larger plans.  One option is to use `TRY_CONVERT` to still view some plans, although there will still be nulls for the larger plans.  Note that using either `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` to replace nulls in the `query_plan` column in `dm_exec_text_query_plan` won't work, as data type of the result for `COALESCE` will be the data type of the higher precedence (being XML in this instance) and for `ISNULL` this will be the data type of the first argument, thus leading the same XML conversion error as before.  If you want to view larger plans from `dm_exec_text_query_plan` then you may need to look into another option such as C#.

```
SELECT 
    TRY_CONVERT(XML, p.query_plan) AS QueryPlan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans ps
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(ps.plan_handle, 0, -1) p
```